# node.js get results from mysql query using custom module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How I can get select query results?
I am getting empty/null.Also after reading some article I tried callback logic and tried the callback function but no luck so far.

My Custom Module all code is below.

```
module.exports = {
    all: function (cb) {

        con.query("SELECT * from `posts`", function (err, posts, fileds) {
            if (err) {
                return cb(null, err);
            } else {
                return cb(null, posts);
            }
            // console.dir(posts);
        });
    },
    store: function (req, res, next) {

        // get values..
        const title = req.body.title;
        const body = req.body.body;
        const filename = (req.file != null) ? req.file.filename : null;
        var sql = "INSERT INTO `posts` (`post_id`, `title`, `body`,`file`, `created_at`) VALUES (NULL, '" + title + "', '" + body + "', '" + filename + "', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
        con.query(sql, function (err) {
            console.log('Error' + err);
        });

        next();

        // redirect
        res.redirect("/admin/post");
    },
    delete: function (req, res, next) {},
    edit: function (req, res, next) {},
    update: function (req, res, next) {}
}
```

I have tried cb(callback) but it says

> TypeError: cb is not a function

No luck in getting results.
Please guide and help.

also I am getting all function data in another file like this

```
var postModel = require('../models/posts');
console.log("admin.js :" + postModel.all());
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter should be callback function like below.

```
postModel.all(function(response) {
    console.log(response);//you will get result here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Created simple callback function and it solved my issue. please see below code.

```
    module.exports = {
    all: function (callback) {

        const newLocal = function (err, posts) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(null, err);
            }
            else {
                // console.dir(posts);
                return callback(posts);
            }
        };
        con.query("SELECT * from `posts`", newLocal);
    },
    store: function (req, res, next) {

        // get values..
        const title = req.body.title;
        const body = req.body.body;
        const filename = (req.file != null) ? req.file.filename : null;
        var sql = "INSERT INTO `posts` (`post_id`, `title`, `body`,`file`, `created_at`) VALUES (NULL, '" + title + "', '" + body + "', '" + filename + "', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
        con.query(sql, function (err) {
            console.log('Error' + err);
        });

        next();

        // redirect
        res.redirect("/admin/post");
    },
    delete: function (req, res, next) {},
    edit: function (req, res, next) {},
    update: function (req, res, next) {}
}
```

Updated code is:

```
const newLocal = function (err, posts) {
if (err) {
 return callback(null, err);
}
 else {
 // console.dir(posts);
 return callback(posts);
}
};
con.query("SELECT * from `posts`", newLocal);
```